# How to detect which Quickbird data product?

Tags: imagery

I have some Quickbird imagery, for further processing I would like to know what kind of data product are these images. The imagery only has an additional text file containing some order numbers.

Quickbird delivers Basic imagery were Orthorectification must be done. Ore they deliver Standard Imagery which is unsuitable for orthorectification.

It seems not to be a Ortho Ready Standard Imagery Product because with the data there was no RPC file.

Here is an example of [Readme.txt of Quickbird imagery][1]
Here is [product description](http://glcf.umd.edu/library/guide/QuickBird_Product_Guide.pdf) from Digital Globe.

```
[1]: ftp://96.53.39.210/pools/A/A0/WorldSatFTP/052761023120_01_README.TXT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file name:

[image]

for example :

11SEP17162134-S2AS_R1C1-052761023120_01_P002.TIF

S2AS in the filename means :

- S: Pan Sharpened
- 2A: Standar (No orthorectified)
- S: Single/Sub-scene